# How to return anonymous array?

Tags: c#

What are the syntax rules for creating an anonymous array?

i.e.

```
int[] function()
{
   int element1 = 1;
   int element2 = 2;
   return //array with element1 and element2
{
```

And what other uses does it have?

Comment: If you need syntax and general information, try Google. First result for "C# Anonymous Array": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx

Comment: I'm not asking for implicitly typed arrays. Anonymous arrays don't bound itself to identities.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
return new int[] { element1, element2 };
```

> And what other uses does it have?

I'm not sure what you mean here I'm afraid.

Comment: You may not even need to specify int, since it can be inferred from the elements.

Answer (score 3):

```
return new int[] {element1, element2};
```

Inline declaration.

Answer (score -3):

You can't return anonymous type and `int[]` is not anonymous

Comment: OP wants an "anonymous array", not an "anonymous type". It's shaky terminology but this interpretation is too literal, I think.